# How do I get this JavaScript / moment code to work with both US and UK date formats?

Tags: javascript, json, date, momentjs

How do I get this JavaScript / moment code to work with both US (MM/DD/YYYY) and UK (DD/MM/YYYY) date formats?  Currently it only works with a UK format:

```
moment.fn.toJSON = function() { 
    return this.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mmZ"); 
};
function submitform() {
    document.getElementById("st_dt_tm").value = 
moment(document.getElementById("inp-st").value, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm").toJSON();
        return true;
};
```

Comment: Accepting the moment as a parameter instead of having it hard-coded is a first step.

Comment: OK, I'd thought of that, but how do you switch on the date format?

Comment: Moment already has a [`toJSON` function](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-json/), by the way...

Comment: @RobG thanks. I just learned something new and for that I am grateful. I removed my previous comment as it could lead to more problems than solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way, by date format alone, to know if it is `DD/MM/YYYY` or `MM/DD/YYYY` because of dates like `01/02/2016`, which is a valid (but different) date either way.

Your choices are:

Use `MM/DD/YYYY` for US dates and `DD-MM-YYYY` for European dates, which is similar to what the JavaScript `Date` object does, but even that is not entirely useful -- more details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

The "best" option is to use some kind of cultural indicator flag -- either something passed in from the back-end code, or perhaps asking JavaScript to format a date for you and looking at what format they use -- and changing strings accordingly.

Comment: How do you ask "JavaScript to format a date for you"?

Comment: @tyebillion -  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: The phrase "European dates" should probably be "everywhere else". ;-)

Comment: @RobG I thought about that, then I figured I'd have someone from the middle east talking about their weird calendar and dates. :)

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher—yes, there are lots of calendar systems, some of which may also be used in the US, but the Date object only supports the [*Gregorian system*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-year-number). BTW, I think it's an error to associate a date format with a regional language, or to use the term "locale" as a pseudonym, but I'm not part of the relevant ECMA standards body. :-( Far better to simply use non–ambiguous values, e.g. "1 July 2016" or "July 1 2016" are unambiguous regardless of "culture" or "locale". ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think the date / time picker I'm using supports the non-ambiguous "1st jan 2017" style format: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/